# Get product details from a webpage using python and selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I have a requirement to **scrape** some data from web pages.I'm using selenium with Python for that but was unable to get the desired results.If anyone can suggest me what to do or how i can change the code to get the desired results it will be very helpful.

I need to get the results in following order Position, Name of Product, URL and company name.

The script below is able to get all the title names but with extra "\n" characters and not able to get other details.Can anyone please help me with it or give suggestions on this please?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument(" — incognito")
#browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver/', chrome_options=option)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/users/user_1566/downloads/chrome_driver/chromedriver', chrome_options=option)

browser.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=samsung+note10')
#items = len(browser.find_elements_by_class_name("cu-container"))
#items = len(browser.find_elements_by_class_name("mnr-c pla-unit"))
#print(items)
timeout = 20
try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='top-pla-group-inner']")))
except TimeoutException:
    print('Timed out waiting for page to load')
    #browser.quit()

titles_element = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='mnr-c pla-unit']")
# use list comprehension to get the actual repo titles and not the selenium objects.
titles = [x.text for x in titles_element]
# print out all the titles.
print('titles:')
print(titles, '\n')

language_element = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class=''plantl pla-unit-single-clickable-target clickable-card']")
print(language_element)
# same concept as for list-comprehension above.
languages = [x.text for x in language_element]
print("languages:")
print(languages, "\n")


for title, language in zip(titles, languages):
    print("RepoName : Language")
    print(title + ": " + language, "\n")
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

Expected output from the URL https://www.google.com/search?q=samsung+note10

```
    Position  Company_Name     Product_Name                                 URL 

    1         CHECK24          Samsung Galaxy Note10 256 GB 
                               glow mit Vertrag + Allnet Flat bei
```

Comment: can we add output here?

Comment: @SHASHIKUMARKL Yes Sure. I will add the output here and it will be really helpful if you can guide.https://www.google.com/search?q=samsung+note10 this is the URL  and the sample output  will add above.

Comment: @SHASHIKUMARKL Any suggestions or modifications ?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
details=browser.find_elements_by_class_name("pymv4e")
for i in details:
    print(str(i))
```

after that you display as you wanted

Comment: I'm getting the output as below  
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="f6182780e04a00f9fb497ca878748e86", element="285c8617-6ace-4b55-9ff8-72dc060a8c00")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="f6182780e04a00f9fb497ca878748e86", element="4cea16c8-eb96-4955-bb1a-e44d0e7ca104")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="f6182780e04a00f9fb497ca878748e86", element="2aeeb4c7-1fa0-41f0-9390-f2df09c815d2")>

Comment: Any other solutions or things to do?

Comment: or DO you know how to create a TEXT file with all the content from a DIV class?

Comment: .getText() method

Comment: i want to get entire content of divclass "top-pla-group-inner"and save it as TEXT file,have tried like it but not fetting the contents of DIV clas items = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("top-pla-grou-inner").getText() 
print(items)

Comment: Any suggestions?